# Where to put version __v in redux state?

Tags: mongodb, redux

I have a model that is scattered all around the application. I have a redux state tree:

```
{
  page: {
     modelPart1: ...,
     ... : {
        modelPart2: ...
     }
}
```

I need to keep a reference to mongoDb `__v` in my state too. Where is the best place to place it?

I was thinking about a separate branch `model_metadata` that would keep the metadata about docs (_id, __v, ...).

```
   {
      model_metadata: { <------------------------ HERE
        model: { 
          _id: id,
          __v: 2
        }
      }
      page: {
         modelPart1: ...,
         ... : {
            modelPart2: ...
         }
    }
```

Is it a valid approach or would you recommend a different one?

Answer (score 1):

Every reducer only can access its own part of state, so when you do

```
combineReducers({
  one,
  another
});
```

and access `state` in `one`, it is equivalent to doing `store.getState().one`, and the same for `another`. So, you need to split the data in `page` property of state into two parts: actual data and metadata. Just like the object you retrieve from Mongo.

The point in having metadata and actual data being processed by the same reducer is that every time a reducer function is performed, you have everything you need about your object in `state` argument of that function. Splitting the data into two different reducers would make things way more complicated.

So, the new data representation in `page` would look like

```
{
   model_metadata: { <------------------------ HERE
     model: { 
       _id: id,
       __v: 2
     }
   }
   page: {
      modelPart1: ...,
      ... : {
         modelPart2: ...
      }
 }
```

while connecting to `page` would look like

```
connect(state => ({
  page: state.page
})(...)
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help Rishat. A question. When you say "data representation in `page` would look like" then you copy pasted my code on purpose? Didn't you want to modify it? In my case I am accessing the model across several pages. Then when pressing the save I am "collecting" all the data about the model across the app.

Comment: That's totally on purpose. The idea is that not `state.page` but `state.page.page` now contains page data.

Comment: Yeah, that's very similar to my approach. Why not. :) Have you used it in your project?

Comment: I haven't, but if I did, I would just mix metadata and entity data in a single object, because that wouldn't do any bad as long as property names don't run into collision (two identical properties representing different stuff, very unlikely to happen).